# Upload large files to the Google Drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

In my app, I'm uploading files to the google drive using **GD API**. It works fine for small file sizes, but when file size is large (ex: 200MB), it throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:` exception. I know why it crashes it loads the whole data into the memory, can anyone suggest how can I fix this problem?

This is my code:

```
OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
FileInputStream fis;

try {
     fis = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
     int n;
     while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
            baos.write(buf, 0, n);
     byte[] photoBytes = baos.toByteArray();
     outputStream.write(photoBytes);

     outputStream.close();
     outputStream = null;
     fis.close();
     fis = null;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                   
}
```

Comment: It's no doubt that you need to use a smaller buffer, writing by chunks.

Comment: Can you show  some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line would allocate 200 MB of RAM and can definitely cause OutOfMemoryError exception:

```
byte[] photoBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Why are you not writing directly to your `outputStream`:

```
while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
        outputStream.write(buf, 0, n);
```