# Resumable Upload - Google Drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api

Hello I'm trying to implement [Resumable Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload) from google drive API, but I'm facing an issue.

Have someone been capable of running the above code from the java [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-upload) from google?

```
File mediaFile = new File("/tmp/Test.jpg");
InputStreamContent mediaContent =
    new InputStreamContent("image/jpeg",
        new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(mediaFile)));
mediaContent.setLength(mediaFile.length());

MediaHttpUploader uploader = new MediaHttpUploader(mediaContent, transport, httpRequestInitializer);
uploader.setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener());
HttpResponse response = uploader.upload(requestUrl);
if (!response.isSuccessStatusCode()) {
  throw GoogleJsonResponseException(jsonFactory, response);
}
```

I need to know how to declare/create the **transport** variable and **httpRequestInitializer**.

Or an example to perform big upload of files to the google system.

Answer (score 0):

[`HttpRequestInitializer`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.19.0/com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer) is a basic authentication HTTP request initializer as specified in [Basic Authentication Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2).

For example, this might be used to disable request timeouts:

```
public class DisableTimeout implements HttpRequestInitializer {
  public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
    request.setConnectTimeout(0);
    request.setReadTimeout(0);
  }
}
```

As you've said, you need to use the [resumable media upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload) to upload/send large files chunk by chunk. For example, the `insert` method of the [Drive API](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v2.1beta/rest) supports `mediaUpload`, and you can use the following code to upload a file:

```
class CustomProgressListener implements MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener {
  public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
    switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
      case INITIATION_STARTED:
        System.out.println("Initiation has started!");
        break;
      case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
        System.out.println("Initiation is complete!");
        break;
      case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
        System.out.println(uploader.getProgress());
        break;
      case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
        System.out.println("Upload is complete!");
    }
  }
}

File mediaFile = new File("/tmp/driveFile.jpg");
InputStreamContent mediaContent =
    new InputStreamContent("image/jpeg",
        new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(mediaFile)));
mediaContent.setLength(mediaFile.length());

Drive.Files.Insert request = drive.files().insert(fileMetadata, mediaContent);
request.getMediaHttpUploader().setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener());
request.execute();
```

Here are some references which might also help:

- [Upload large files to the Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698519/upload-large-files-to-the-google-drive)
- https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/issues/853

Comment: This is using the V3 version? I'm capable of doing this in V2 not in V3